# Sorting represented data from a dictionary

Tags: sorting, csv, dictionary, wxpython

I am trying to sort my data, something similar to sorting example in here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/04/wxpython-wx-listctrl-tips-and-tricks/

But for some reason when my data is represented in the table, things are all over the place. For example, the computer name does not match the owner. At first I though that the dictionary was not create correctly. But then I tried printing it and the dictionary looks perfectly fine. So, the error must be somewhere in lines with list_ctrl. Do you see where my mistake is?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix
import csv
from wxPython.wx import *

key_index = 4

##########################################################################
info = csv.reader(open(report.csv', 'rb'),delimiter=',')
length = 0
info_list = []

for row in info: #search each row in the report
    info_list.append([length,row[1],row[4]])
    length = length + 1

dict_info = {}
rows = 0

for item in info_list:
    dict_info[item[rows]] = (item[rows + 1], item[rows + 2])
####################################################################
class TestListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                    size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
########################################################################
class TestListCtrlPanel(wx.Panel, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.index = 0

        self.list_ctrl = TestListCtrl(self, size=(-1,100),style=wx.LC_REPORT
                                        |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN|wx.LC_SORT_ASCENDING)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Computer Name")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Owner")

        items = dict_info.items()
        index = 0
        for key, data in items:
            self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, data[0])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, data[1])
            self.list_ctrl.SetItemData(self.index, key)
            index += 1

        # Now that the list exists we can init the other base class,
        # see wx/lib/mixins/listctrl.py
        self.itemDataMap = dict_info
        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, 2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_COL_CLICK, self.OnColClick, self.list_ctrl)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Used by the ColumnSorterMixin, see wx/lib/mixins/listctrl.py
    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self.list_ctrl

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnColClick(self, event):
        print "column clicked"
        event.Skip()

########################################################################

###################################################################


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                            "Search")

        panel = TestListCtrlPanel(self) #create a panel


#run code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you copied and pasted my code but changed a critical piece. You need to change the for loop in your **init** to look like this:

```
for key, data in items:
    print "%s: %s - %s" % (key, data[0], data[1])
    print
    self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, data[0])
    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, data[1])
    self.list_ctrl.SetItemData(index, key)
    index += 1
```

The "self.index" that I left in my example is set to zero, but I never use it in that loop. Instead I create a local variable called **index** and use that instead. I have fixed my article by removing the **self.index** bit since it is unneeded in that particular example.

In your code, you increment index, but use self.index in all your self.list_ctrl.*() methods.

Comment: IMplementing your change it only prints correctly to the terminal. The GUI is still not working well. "Computer Name" collumn looks fine but the "Owner" collumn looks empty. Any ides on what the problem could be? And great article, btw, it has some very cool stuff in it!

Comment: It is strange because when I create my dict_info manually like you did in your example the code works fine. But when I convert my list to a dictionary like in my code then the GUI is not created correctly. I tried printing your dictionary and my dictionary and the format looks identical. I don't know what could be wrong, both codes look identical.

Comment: You'll probably have to provide the file you're creating the dict from for anyone to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've been learning from Mike Driscoll's post on mixin's.
http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/04/wxpython-wx-listctrl-tips-and-tricks/
Make any text comma delimiter file.
This is better approach:

```
import csv
import sys
import wx
import  wx.lib.mixins.listctrl  as  listmix

info = csv.reader(open('yourFile.txt', 'rb'),delimiter=',')
sortedlist = sorted(info, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

length = 0
textDB = []
for row in sortedlist: 
    textDB.append([length,row[0],row[1]])
    length = length + 1
dict_info = {}
rows = 0

for item in textDB:
    dict_info[item[rows]] = (item[rows + 1], item[rows + 2])

class TestListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin) :    
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                  size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0) :        
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)        
        listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)

class TabPanel(wx.Panel, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin) :
    ''' This will be [ inserted into ] the second notebook tab. '''    
    def __init__(self, parent) :        
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)        
        self.createAndLayout()    

    def createAndLayout(self) :        
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL)
        self.list = TestListCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.LC_REPORT
                                 | wx.BORDER_NONE
                                 | wx.LC_EDIT_LABELS
                                 | wx.LC_SORT_ASCENDING)        
        sizer.Add(self.list, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.populateList()        
        self.itemDataMap = textDB
        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, 3)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)

    def populateList(self) :        
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'F1')
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'F2')
#        self.list.InsertColumn(2, 'F3')
        items = dict_info.items()        
        for key, data in items :
            index = self.list.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, data[0])
            self.list.SetStringItem(index, 0, data[0])
            self.list.SetStringItem(index, 1, data[1])
#            self.list.SetStringItem(index, 2, data[2])
            self.list.SetItemData(index, key)          

        self.list.SetColumnWidth(0, wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE)
        self.list.SetColumnWidth(1, wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE)
#        self.list.SetColumnWidth(2, wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE)

        self.list.SetItemState(5, wx.LIST_STATE_SELECTED, wx.LIST_STATE_SELECTED)
        item = self.list.GetItem(1)
        item.SetTextColour(wx.BLUE)
        self.list.SetItem( item )
        item = self.list.GetItem(4)
        item.SetTextColour(wx.RED)
        self.list.SetItem(item)
        self.currentItem = 0

    def GetListCtrl(self) :
        """ Used by the ColumnSorterMixin, see wx/lib/mixins/listctrl.py """
        return self.list

if __name__ == "__main__" :    
    class DemoFrame(wx.Frame) :
        def __init__(self) :
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, title="Panel Tutorial",
                               size=(600, 300))            
            panel = TabPanel(self)
            self.Show()    
    app = wx.App()
    frame = DemoFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This looks pretty good, although I don't think you need to specify the delimiter in this case since the csv module should default to a comma